# How to transform multiple models or controllers into one? in the mvc pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, refactoring

In my project, I apply the mvc pattern and I have many tables in my database. I end up having many controllers and models to manage the data in these tables. My question: is there any way or pattern to reduce the number of controllers and models? How to transform multiple models or controllers into one?

Comment: I suggest you to post the code of at least one controller and one model of yours. Also, a description of how exactly you're applying the MVC pattern in your app is welcome. This way, the SO users will have a better perspective and will, hopefully, give you a proper advice.

Comment: Checkout the Facade Pattern.